# Change tags of all special characters using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<all>
<Others>1</Others>
<O>(</O>
<B-XREF>1</B-XREF>
<O>)</O>
</authors>
<Others>From</Others></all>
```

I want to change the tags of all tags containing special characters to `<special>,</special>` replace all tags like this.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match=".">
        <special>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </special>
    </xsl:template>
```

I domt wanna do this, Any othe way around ?

The xml should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<all>
<Others>1</Others>
<authors>
<special>)</special>
<special>,</special> ........
```

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Comment: Are you really asking how to replace `<O>x</O>` with `<special>x</special>` where `x` stands for any special character? Are all special characters currently surrounded by `<O></O>`?

Comment: yep , you are correct @JimGarrison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `identity transform` template to copy the input as is to the output and then modify the `<O>` elements to `<special>`.

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="O">
    <special>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </special>      
</xsl:template>
```